# Why my script throws error?

Tags: bash

---

the following bash script shows an erro.How can i overcome this those errors.

```
#!/cpd/misc/bin/bash
while[1];
do date "+%T";
sleep 60;
done
```

Errors:

```
./bash1.sh: line 2: while[1]: command not found
./bash1.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./bash1.sh: line 3: `do date "+%T";'
```

Comment: Plug for shellcheck.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of mistakes:

- You need a whitespace after `while`, before the condition
- `[1]` is wrong in bash, presumably you wanted to use something that has truth value 1. If so, use either `:` or `true`, these two are most common and readable
- Also as the commands are separated by newline, you don't need the `;`s at the end of each line

So you can do:

```
#!/cpd/misc/bin/bash
while :
do 
    date "+%T" 
    sleep 60
done
```

Comment: I'd prefer `while true;`, but `while [ 1 ];` works, it tests if the string `1` is not empty.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, that would do `[ -n 1 ]` test, but that might give most people wrong idea of things (and also OP has not used the spaces around). I prefer the readable `true` too, although have an inclination towards laziness hence `:` ;)

Answer (score 0):

`while` must be followed by a space.

What do you think `[1]` does, though? If there's a file named `1`, it will be matched, so bash will see `while 1`, and if `1` weren't executable and in $PATH, it would fail. If there's no `1`, bash will try to run `[1]` and probably fail again, because no one sane names their executable scripts and programs `[1]`.